# Filter the data with Api response scope value in angular js

Tags: angular

```js
<!-- JS Code -->
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []); myapp.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { $scope.detailsone = result; //Api response Array format stored in this variable $scope.detailstwo = result; //Api response Array format stored in this variable }]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head> </head>

<body ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div> Button 1 </div> // click on button 1 it will redirect to firstdetail.html(using UI Router). firstdetail.html and controller is firstctrl
    <div> Button 2 </div> // click on button 2 it will redirect to seconddetail.html(using UI Router). seconddetail.html and controller is secondctrl
    <!--Sample firstdetail.html-->
    <div> <a href=""> First Detail Click </a> // Click here it will redirect to detail.html with this value $scope.detailsone(API call) </div>
    <!--Sample firstdetail.html-->
    <div> <a href=""> Second Detail Click </a> // Click here it will also redirect to detail.html with this value $scope.detailstwo(API call) </div>
    <!--This is sample format of detail.html--><strong>I want to show div1 details when i click on button1
                and I want to show div2 details when i click on button2 and div1 and div2 htmls are in same page.
                    problem is it's not working properly. suppose i clicked on button 2 it fails to load api at that time it showing div1 details. how can i differentiate this data based on ajax response stored scope value.</strong>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1-details" ng-if="!detailstwo">
            <div> Div1 Heading </div>
            <div> Div1 Table </div>
            <div> Div1 Pagination </div>
        </div>
        <div class="div2-details" ng-if="!!detailstwo">
            <div> Div2 Heading </div>
            <div> Div3 Table </div>
            <div> Div4 Pagination </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular js  -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you put brief description along with code? Unable to understand where you are applying filter? There are tons of external js libraries to filter data. **lodash** is one of great.

Comment: e2eservice.getTrendDetail(detailnamefilter, $rootScope.trendallobj, trendfilterObj).then(function (result) {
                if (result.errors) {
                    console.log('Error');
                    $scope.errorDetailMsg = true;
                }

Comment: else {
                    $scope.errorDetailMsg = false;
                    $rootScope.trenddetails = result;
                    var trendtotalPage = result.PAGE_COUNT;
                    var trendrange = [];
                    for (var i = 1; i <= trendtotalPage; i++) {
                        trendrange.push(i);
                    }
                    $rootScope.trendnumOfPage = trendrange;
                }
            });

Comment: Based on this value "$rootScope.trenddetails" we need to filter

Comment: Arun, I would suggest to edit your question properly and not to add code in comments.